# How can I bind the default FBO in GLKViewController

Tags: glkit, fbo

I'm a new for OpenGL ES with GLKit, I want to create two FBO for my program. but I don't know how to bind the default FBO, anyone who can help me ?

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: in fact, I hope to create another FBO, and doing some thing in this two FBO, I want to bind different FBO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is basic, you just need add one line like this:

```
[((GLKView *) self.view) bindDrawable];
```

this method can reset to GLKit default FBO

Comment: of course, you can get the sample code in github:      https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/minimalfbo